# XCODE/Swift Autolayout ScrollView with dynamic label, textview etc. How set scrollview height based on textview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am using: Swift, autolayout and creating all views in storyboard. I do modify the content programatically.
I have following design; black boxes is pictures, below picture a date and topic, below that a title, and at the bottom I have a textview which gets loaded from a websource. I have disabled scroll on textview, as I want only the scrollview to scroll.
So how would be the best way to solve this, so i will be able to scroll to the bottom of the textview, showing me all the text?

My idea is to somehow retrieve the contentheight of the textview after loading contents into it (ViewDidLoad). Then add this to the height of the scrollview deducted from the original height of the textview. But must say, it seems tough for something which i thought would be standard functionality. 
Any ideas on this?

My code does look like this, so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
 {
    println("Height: \(self.textView.frame.height)") // prints 222.0
    let contentSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(self.textView.bounds.size)
    var frame = textView.frame
    frame.size.height = contentSize.height
    textView.frame = frame
    println("Height: \(self.textView.frame.height)") // prints 283.5
 }
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    println("Height: \(self.textView.frame.height)")  //prints 222.0

    //self.textView.delegate = self
}
```

Code Example 2:

```
let sizeThatFits = CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
    //CGSize sizeThatFits = [self.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)]
    self.textViewHeight = sizeThatFits.height
```

Error Message: NSNumber is not a subtype of NSLayoutConstraint.

Below seems to be okay with syntax.
Code Example 3:

```
self.textView.addObserver(self, forkeypath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: nil)
```

[image: Screenshot of design]

[image: Constraints]

Comment: How are you creating the views? storyboard or code? are you using auto layout?

Comment: Storyboard, modifying content with code and using autolayout. Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrollviews are a little bit complicated when it comes to auto layout, which makes working with them more difficult.

You probably have a width and height constraint for you textView in the storyboard(otherwise you will have ambiguous contentSize warnings for the scrollView).

I found a solution for your problem, just tried it out and it works great.

First, you need to create an outlet from the UITextView height constraint in your viewController:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewHeightConstraint;

@end
```

Then, in viewDidLoad you add yourself as an observer for the `contentSize` property on the `textView`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // All you other stuff ...

    [self.textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
}
```

Then in the `observeValueForKeyPath`, you update the height constraint for the `textView`, something like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    [self.textViewHeightConstraint setConstant:self.textView.contentSize.height];
}
```

Then don't forget to remove the observer so you don't have a crash

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.textView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
}
```

For this to work you have to make sure you have top and bottom offset constraints from the `textView` to the `scrollView`.

If you need more help, just let me know.

---

### Update - Swift

This is how your implementation should look like if you are using swift

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override
    func viewDidLoad (){
        textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textView.contentSize.height
    }

    deinit {
        self.textView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like I'm on right track. I updated question with code example 3. Having problem with obj-c to swift i guess.

Comment: So, did you get it to work? Or you still have trouble with it?

Comment: Nah. Still trouble:
The code example 3, is placed in the viewDidLoad method of the viewController. 
Where should i place "observeValueForKeyPath"
And what about the remove observer function, where should i place it?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some sample code in swift.

Comment: Catalina T. Thank you so much :-)
It works.
Just to grasp it - I can actually use this function to look for other height constraints changing aswell right?

Comment: You're welcome! Great that it does :) The method will get called when the `contentSize` changes, because that is  what you registered for. If you register to observe other properties, the same method will be called. But this is not a solution for all problems, depending on what you are trying to achieve, other solutions might work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the height constraint of the text view as IBOutlet to your file. After loading, it's a simple update:

```
CGSize sizeThatFits = [self.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.textview.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];

self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFits.height;
```